# Eigen SparseQR gives different results than from others: bdcSVD, conjugategradient

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3, svd

I have tried to solver linear system Ax = b using eigen solvers (Eigen 3.3.7). However, I found the results (x) solved by SparseQR is different with results from dense solver (bdcsvd) and also other sparse solver, but the relative errors (||Ax - b|| / ||b||) are same.

Could someone can help me to understand why sparseQR gives different results and how to make sure it gives the same results as from SVD?

I also have noticed that for some other datasets, sparseQR and SVD give the same results, but not from CG.

Thank you.

Matrix A and b can be found in below.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A; // reading from a file, see below for a simple sample
Eigen::MatrixXd b; // reading from a file

Eigen::VectorXd x_svd = A.bdcSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(b);

//convert to sparse matrix
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> As = A.sparseView(0.1, 1e-5);

tau = 1e-3; // check coefficients are close or not

// SparseQR
{
Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> solver;
//solver.setPivotThreshold(1e-10);
solver.compute(As);
if (solver.info() != Eigen::Success)
    std::cout << "SparseQR::Decomposition Failed" << std::endl; 
Eigen::VectorXd xs = solver.solve(b);

if (solver.info() != Eigen::Success)
    std::cout << "SparseQR::Solving Failed" << std::endl;
std::string str_equal = xs.isApprox(x_svd, tau) ? " Equal" : " UnEqual";
std::cout << "Results::" << str_equal << std::endl;
std::cout << "EstimatedError: " << (As * xs - b).norm() / b.norm() << std::endl;
}

// ConjugateGradient
{
Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > solver(As.transpose() * As);
if (solver.info() != Eigen::Success)
    std::cout << "CG::Decomposition Failed" << std::endl;
Eigen::VectorXd xcg = solver.solve(As.transpose() * b);
if (solver.info() != Eigen::Success)
    std::cout << "CG::Solving Failed" << std::endl;

std::cout << "#Iterations: " << solver.iterations() << std::endl;
std::cout << "EstimatedError: " << solver.error() << std::endl;
std::string str_equal = corr.isApprox(para_coeff, tau) ? " Equal" : " UnEqual";
std::cout << "Results::" << str_equal << std::endl;
}
```

Matrix A:

```
     0  35516      0  17732 -35516      0 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0  17732      0  35516 -17732      0 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0 -35516      0 -17732  35516      0  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0 -17732      0 -35516  17732      0  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0  35516      0  17732 -35516      0 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0  17732      0  35516 -17732      0 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0 -35516      0 -17732  35516      0  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0 -17732      0 -35516  17732      0  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  35516      0  17732 -35516      0 -17732      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  17732      0  35516 -17732      0 -35516      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516      0 -17732  35516      0  17732      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732      0 -35516  17732      0  35516      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  35516      0  17732 -35516      0 -17732      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  17732      0  35516 -17732      0 -35516      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516      0 -17732  35516      0  17732      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732      0 -35516  17732      0  35516      0
     0      0  35516  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0  17732  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0 -35516 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  35516  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0 -17732 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  17732  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0  35516  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0  17732  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  35516  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  17732  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  35516  17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516 -17732      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  17732  35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732 -35516      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -35516 -17732      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  35516  17732      0      0
     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 -17732 -35516      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  17732  35516      0      0
```

b

```
      225915
     -380755
     -225915
      380755
 1.68807e+07
 9.48266e+06
-1.68807e+07
-9.48266e+06
    -32610.3
 -1.5961e+06
     32610.3
  1.5961e+06
-1.08558e+07
 1.41591e+06
 1.08558e+07
-1.41591e+06
-2.79489e+06
-4.57751e+06
 2.79489e+06
 4.57751e+06
 1.22018e+06
 3.70838e+06
-1.22018e+06
-3.70838e+06
-4.80155e+06
-2.53063e+06
 4.80155e+06
 2.53063e+06
```

Comment: I can re-create the results as you described. I even tried using SuiteSparse's SPQR and got the same solution as Eigen's Sparse QR. One suggestion that might help with your other data sets where CG gave different results: use Eigen::LeastSquaresConjugateGradient. This may mitigate some error and should be  faster for larger systems.

Comment: @CharlieS Thank you for your kind help. I have also tried LeastSquaresCOnjugateGradient, BiCGSTAB, and also tried numpy.linalg.lstsq, they all yield the same results as the result yielded by BdcSVD and CG. Only SparseQR gives significantly different result.

Comment: @CharlieS, The weird thing is when I change to a different system (2 non-zeros in each rows, instead of 4-non-zeros in the above system), qr and bdcsvd give the same solution as the solution should be, but CG, LeastSquaresCG gives significantly different results.
thanks.

Comment: refer to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760558/using-qr-decomposition-to-solve-a-system-of-equations-with-a-singular-matrix 

"Note that the QR decomposition can be less numerically reliable for solving rank-deficient problems than the SVD, or, more precisely, the truncated SVD approach."

Your matrix is very rank deficient, so this explanation fits your observations. The best explanation I have is that your matrix is a very difficult system to analyze, and SVD is suited for such problems. Unfortunately, I don't know of a mainstream sparse SVD algorithm.